# Squid external_acl_type configuration

Tags: squid

Hey i am trying to implement a custom authentication for squid. I am not too sure what is wrong with the code below. It never checks with the python script and just let proxy requests through. Dont have experience with squid appreciate the help Thanks!

```
external_acl_type custom_acl %LOGIN %MYADDR /home/python_test.py

http_access allow all
http_port 3128

acl ip4001 myip 172.0.0.2
tcp_outgoing_address 172.0.0.2 ip4001
acl ip4002 myip 172.0.0.2
tcp_outgoing_address 172.0.0.2 ip4002
acl ip4003 myip 172.0.0.3
tcp_outgoing_address 172.0.0.3 ip4003
```